# How can I run command line programs with GUI in UBUNTU Desktop?

Tags: command-line

I recently installed ubuntu desktop and started its GUI with `startx` and now I want to run commands like `tar` `lamp` etc, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T.

Now enter your commands...

Easy day ;D